# Использование sync.pool golang

Tags: golang, pool, golang-struct

Пытаюсь разобраться с sync.Pool в golang. Как я понял, основная задача sync.Pool хранить адреса памяти для последующего их использования без аллокации. Соответственно в такое случае приложение не должно разрастаться в оперативной памяти. Так ли это?

В качестве примера написал следующий код, который использует pool. Грамотно ли таким образом работать с пулом? Спасибо за ответы.

```
type Query struct {
    ID         int
    Name       string
    Type_query string
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Microsecond)
        query := getQueryPool()
        query.(*Query).ID = 111
        query.(*Query).Name = "bbb"
        query.(*Query).Type_query = "aaa"

        putPool(query)
    }
}

var queryPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return new(Query)
    },
}

// Возьмём память из пула
func getQueryPool() (b interface{}) {
    mem := queryPool.Get()
    if mem != nil {
        b = mem.(*Query)
    }

    return
}

// Очистим структуру
func (q *Query) Reset() {
    q.ID = 0
    q.Name = ""
    q.Type_query = ""
}

// Вернём выделенную память в буфер
func putPool(b interface{}) {
    switch b := b.(type) {
    case *Query:
        b.Reset()
        queryPool.Put(b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Разрешите поправить ваш код:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Query struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
    TypeQuery string
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Microsecond)
        query := getQueryPool()

        query.ID = i
        query.Name = strconv.Itoa(i)
        query.TypeQuery = "query"
      
        fmt.Println(query.ID)
        query.Reset() 
        putPool(query)
    }
}

var queryPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return &Query{}
    },
}

// получаем структуру из пула
func getQueryPool() *Query {
    mem := queryPool.Get()
    if mem != nil {
        // hello GC
        return &Query{}
    }

    return mem.(*Query)
}

func (q *Query) Reset() {
    *q = Query{}
}

// возвращаем структуру в пул
func putPool(q *Query) {
    queryPool.Put(q)
}
```

Теперь, что касается sync.Pool

Расскажу где он очень полезен, допустим у вас есть какая-то большая структура, инициализация которой затратит очень много аллокаций(выделение памяти) и соответственно будет сильно тормозить вашу программу. Тут можно подумать о sync.Pool. Он заранее заготовит ваши структуры в том объёме в котором он сочтет нужным, этот процесс вы никак не контролируете и не можете ему задать количество. Когда вы вызываете команду Get(), то sync.Pool берет 1 из множества заготовленных элементов и возвращает ее вам. Вы пользуетесь элементом и когда он вам не нужен возвращаете обратно. Тем самым вам не нужно каждый раз создавать структуру (которая очень большая) соответственно вы затратите меньше памяти и ускорите программу.
но лучше изучить по подробнее эту тему, перед тем как ею пользоваться. Надо не забывать, что эти заготовленные структуры сборщик мусора может в какой-то момент затереть.
сам sync.Pool не панацея и к примеру, если ваша структура маленькая или используется редко, то смысла к ней прибегать нету мне кажется.